# Pass one element of tuple as argument along with other arguments

Tags: python, tuples, argument-passing

I have a library function that returns a `tuple` and looks something like this

```
def some_function(some_string):
    does something
    return (text,id)
```

Now I want to pass the text returned from the some_function as argument to another function. The catch is the function has other arguments as well and I don't want to pass the entire tuple as a pointer. I also need need to retrieve many texts that will be generated by different values of some_string.

Depending on the condition met, I want to call another function which will look something like this

```
if abcd:
    other_function(name,phone,**some_function("abcd")**,age)
elif xyz:
    other_function(name,phone,**some_function("xyz")**,age)
else:
    other_function(name,phone,**some_function("aaaa")**,age)
```

So what should I replace **some_function("abcd")** with so that it sends only the text and not both text and id as arguments?

The other_function is defined like this

```
def other_function(name,phone,text,age):
   ...
   return
```

---

One solution that I came up with myself was to create another function that returns just the text.

```
def returntextonly(some_string):
  self.some_string = some_string
  (text,id) = some_function(some_string)
  return text
```

and then call the other_function like

```
 if abcd:
    other_function(name,phone,returntextonly("abcd"),age)
```

I mostly program in C++ and have picked up python only recently. I was wondering if there is a better solution to the problem than creating a new function just to return one element of the tuple.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: A tuple is just a sequence (sequences are like arrays/lists/strings/etc), so you can do `some_function("abcd")[0]` to get the first element of it, which is your text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run this as:

```
other_function(name, phone, some_function("abcd")[0], age)
```

There is no need to define the additional `if` statements, wrapper functions etc, since you want to pass only the first element of the tuple which is returned from the original function.

For the general case, this becomes:

```
other_function(name, phone, some_function(some_string)[0], age)
```

Note that the tuple is another (immutable) iterator, and its elements can be accessed using the regular indexes like in lists.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Didn't know it was that easy in Python :)